# how to align face contour properly in firebase mlkit?

Tags: view, contour, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

i saw a lot of examples and tried creating a face contouring app and everything worked as expected but for whatsoever reason the dots are not being aligned with the actual face.

here is my activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/cvv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cameraFacing="front"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    <com.kirtu.simpletexts.texts.OverlayView
        android:id="@+id/overlayView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the main activity code

```
public class filter extends AppCompatActivity {
    int previewh,previeww;
    CameraView cv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter);
        cv = findViewById(R.id.cvv);
        cv.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        cv.start();
        final OverlayView ov = findViewById(R.id.overlayView);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions op =new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)
                .build();
        final FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector= FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(op);
        cv.addFrameProcessor(new FrameProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void process(@NonNull Frame frame) {
                if(frame.getSize() != null)
                {
                    int rotation = frame.getRotation()/ 90;
                    if(rotation/2 == 0)
                    {
                        previewh = cv.getPreviewSize().getHeight();
                        previeww = cv.getPreviewSize().getWidth();
                        //Log.d("texts", "process: "+cv.getPreviewSize().getWidth()+"  "+cv.getPreviewSize().getHeight());
                    }else
                    {
                        previewh = cv.getPreviewSize().getWidth();
                        previeww = cv.getPreviewSize().getHeight();
                        //Log.d("texts", "process: "+cv.getPreviewSize().getWidth()+"  "+cv.getPreviewSize().getHeight());
                    }
                    FirebaseVisionImageMetadata metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
                            .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
                            .setWidth(frame.getSize().getWidth())
                            .setHeight(frame.getSize().getHeight())
                            .setRotation(rotation)
                            .build();
                    FirebaseVisionImage fvi = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(frame.getData(),metadata);
                    final FirebaseVisionFace[] fc = new FirebaseVisionFace[1];
                    detector.detectInImage(fvi).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {
                           for(FirebaseVisionFace f : firebaseVisionFaces)
                                {
                                    ov.previewh = previewh;
                                    ov.previeww = previeww;
                                    ov.face = f;
                                    ov.invalidate();
                                }

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cv.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cv.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cv.destroy();
    }
}
```

this is the overlay code

```
public class OverlayView extends View {

    public int previewh;
    public int previeww;
    public FirebaseVisionFace face;
    public Rect rect;
    private float widthScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private float heightScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    Context c;
    Bitmap draw = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pimg);


    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        this.c = context;
        this.postInvalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(face!= null && canvas != null && previewh != 0 && previeww != 0)
        {
            widthScaleFactor = getWidth()/previeww;
            heightScaleFactor = getHeight()/previewh;
            float maxx = 0;
            float minx = 10000;
            float maxy = 0;
            float miny = 10000;
            List<FirebaseVisionPoint> facce3= face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.ALL_POINTS).getPoints();
            for(FirebaseVisionPoint f : facce3)
            {
                Paint p1 = new Paint();
                p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                p1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                p1.setStrokeWidth(5);
                canvas.drawPoint(translateX(f.getX()+50),translateY(f.getY()+50),p1);
            }


            maxx = translateX(maxx);
            minx = translateX(minx);
            maxy = translateY(maxy);
            miny = translateY(miny);
            //Log.d("texts", "onDraw: "+maxx+"  "+minx+" "+maxy+"  "+miny);
            Rect r1 = new Rect(Math.round(maxx),Math.round(miny),Math.round(minx),Math.round(maxy));

        }
    }

    private float translateX(Float x) {
        return getWidth()-scaleX(x);
    }

    private float scaleX(Float x) {
        return x*widthScaleFactor;
    }

    private float translateY(Float x) {
        Resources resources = c.getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        return (scaleY(x)+resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId));
    }

    private float scaleY(Float x) { return x*heightScaleFactor; }
}
```

i have tried adjusting the X and Y values by adding some values to it but in the it turned out that one of the side is being not covered by the points then

what can be done to make it properly aligned on all the sides.

Comment: are you set resolution and aspect ratio for your analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [GraphicOverlay.java](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/common/GraphicOverlay.java) on the official *firebase/quickstart-android*'s [repository](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android):

```java
 /**
 * Adjusts the x coordinate from the preview's coordinate system to the view coordinate system.
 */
public float translateX(float x) {
  if (overlay.facing == CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    return overlay.getWidth() - scaleX(x);
  } else {
    return scaleX(x);
  }
}

/**
 * Adjusts the y coordinate from the preview's coordinate system to the view coordinate system.
 */
public float translateY(float y) {
  return scaleY(y);
}
```

Also, you can see the official documentation about face recognition: [Detect Faces with MK Kit on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces).